# Why can I use a set as predicate in clojure?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I'm trying to remove an element from a list or set, like this:

```
(remove :Veronica (list :Veronica :Hailey))
```

It does not work, so, I went to remove documentation, that says I need to pass a predicate to the remove function. But the following code works:

```
(remove #{:foo} [:foo :bar])
(remove #{:foo} (list :foo :bar))
```

#{:foo} is a set. Why does it works?

Is a set a function?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6915531/217324

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why does the following

```
(remove :Veronica (list :Veronica :Hailey))
;(:Veronica :Hailey)
```

- pass muster?
- have no apparent effect?

---

A keyword such as `:Veronica` is a function accepting one argument, hence can be used as a predicate.

But ...

- It expects a map or set argument.
- It then looks itself up in the argument.

For example,

```
(:Veronica #{:Veronica})
;:Veronica

(:Veronica #{1 2 "Buckle my shoe"})
;nil
```

It also forgives useless arguments:

```
(:Veronica 4) ; 4 is not a map or set. 
;nil
```

So `(:Veronica :Veronica)` and `(:Veronica :Hailey)` are both `nil`, so the `remove` in

```
(remove :Veronica (list :Veronica :Hailey))
```

... accomplishes nothing, since the predicate always evaluates false(ish).

---

The other solutions explain why

```
(remove #{:foo} (list :foo :bar))
```

... has the effect you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! @Thumbnail is that the best way to "remove" an element from a collection?

Comment: @renanreismartins If you are looking for a collection that you can rapidly remove (single) elements from, you would be better off using `disj` on a set than `remove` on a list. But you would lose the reliable sequence. A sorted set might give you both.

Answer (score 3):

Sets are functions of their members. If the argument is a member of the set, the member is returned. If the argument is not a member of the set, `nil` is returned. This is documented towards the end of the [Data Structures](http://clojure.org/data_structures) page of the Clojure documentation. To quote that page:

```
(def s #{:a :b :c :d})

(s :b)
-> :b

(s :k)
-> nil
```

Comment: Q: Why is a set a function? A: Sets are functions

Answer (score 2):

Clojure set and map can be work as a function.

```
user=> (#{:foo} :foo)
:foo
user=> (#{:foo} :bar)
nil
```

So, in your code, `#{:foo}` work as a function, and basically the same as

```
(remove (fn [x] (#{:foo} x)) [:foo :bar])
```

For more detail, you can read this: [Clojure: Using Sets and Maps as Functions](http://blog.jayfields.com/2010/08/clojure-using-sets-and-maps-as.html).

Comment: Q: Why is a set a function? A: Sets are functions